# Heroku Rails deploy fails with error "could not connect to server: Connection refused"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Everything works fine locally, but I get that error when I try to push to heroku:

> Running: rake assets:precompile
>
> ```
>    Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL                                                                                                                                                          
>    rake aborted!                                                                                                                                                                                             
>    could not connect to server: Connection refused                                                                                                                                                           
>    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting                                                                                                                                                   
>    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
> ```
>
> /tmp/build_1903c764-07ce-4d06-aa45-6e78dec68af8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize'
>
> ```
>    /tmp/build_1903c764-07ce-4d06-aa45-6e78dec68af8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `new'
> ```
>
> ...
>   etc

I suspect it has to do something with database.yml, so here it is:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: dev-db
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: test-db
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter:  postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: prod-db
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
 # socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: If you type `heroku config` in your console, do you have any reference to the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable?

Comment: Are you a beginner (genuine question -- don't want it to sound condescending!!!)? I think the error is to do with your production database allocation

Comment: @RichPeck, yes there is a link to what I suppose is heroku postgress

Comment: Apparently, in my heroku config vars there are both DATABASE_URL and HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_IVORY_URL, both assigned to the same link

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way you can update your answer with your desired database setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this article](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2012/02/heroku-and-rails-3-2-assetprecompile-error/). The solution is to set

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Comment: The push went throught, but the app won't start now.

Comment: /app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: That's another issue. Please approver this question and open a new one providing the code for the application.rb file.

Answer (score 27):

It might be something related with the fact that you haven't pre-provisioned your database before pushing to heroku. At least, I had a similar error and I solved it by running:

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql
```

You can verify the database was added to your application by running:

```
heroku config
```

And you can read all about this question here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pre-provision-database

Comment: Same here. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is solved, but for others who see this, you might have to promote the database (in case you created a new one, restored to a new one or similar):

`heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_IVORY`(replace IVORY)